# SAS SQL vs Oracle Query not returning same result based on dates

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, sas

I hope that this question makes sense.  I am using SQL within SAS to query an Oracle database.  I also use SQL Developer on the side.  I have a SQL query that I know works but when I try to modify it to work in SAS(T/SQL) the results are not the same.

I'm trying to return customers who had a campaign whose end date was within the month of march 2012.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**WORKING QUERY:**

```
select distinct customer_key
from edw.customer_product_fact
where time_key = '31-jan-12'
and campaign_active = 'Y'
and campaign_cd is not null 
and last_day(campaign_end_date) = add_months(time_key,2)
```

**SAS QUERY:**

```
select distinct customer_key
from edw.customer_product_fact
where time_key = '31-jan-12'd
and campaign_active = 'Y'
and campaign_cd is not null
and intnx('month',campaign_end_date, 0, 'end') =intnx('month', time_key, 2, 'end');
```

I tried using `dateadd` instead of `intnx` but SAS doesn't support it.

Comment: First, use a date format on WHERE time_key=.  You can also put the functions in the SELECT part and compare the returned results.  Have your DBA trace your SAS database session and grab the SQL that is being executed in the database.  The SAS functions get "translated".  That might help understanding what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that the code sample shown as **WORKING QUERY** is something you can run in an Oracle tool and that **SAS QUERY** is something you run using `PROC SQL` (where EDW refers to a previously assigned `LIBNAME` statement).  In the SAS world, this latter sample uses "implicit pass-thru", meaning that your SAS code is translated into Oracle code as best as possible.  That's why `dateadd` (an Oracle function) does not work in SAS.

If you are comfortable writing native Oracle SQL, you might find it easier to use "explicit pass-thru" feature of `PROC SQL`.  One advantage is that you can use SAS macro variables inside your query; they will be "expanded" when processed by Oracle.

In other words, to create a SAS data set named **RESULTS** containing the result of your query, try this:

```
%let MY_PARM = '31-jan-12';
proc sql;
   connect to oracle (user="userid" password="password");
   create table RESULTS as
   select * from connection to oracle (

      select distinct customer_key
      from edw.customer_product_fact
      where time_key = &MY_PARM
        and campaign_active = 'Y'
        and campaign_cd is not null 
        and last_day(campaign_end_date) = add_months(time_key,2)

    );
quit;
```

Everything between the parentheses is submitted directly to Oracle exactly as written, meaning you can take advantage of any Oracle-specific syntax. I'm showing how to use a SAS macro variable (&MY_PARM) just to illustrate the feature; you may not need it.

Comment: That is correct.  This is great!  I didn't realize I could do that.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right, dates stored in Oracle should always be addressed as datetime in SAS. 
Try changing your dates to datetime format or use the datepart function to extract the date portion from a datetime field.

```
select distinct customer_key
from edw.customer_product_fact
where datepart(time_key) = '31jan12'd
and campaign_active = 'Y'
and campaign_cd is not null
and intnx('month',datepart(campaign_end_date), 0, 'end') =intnx('month', datepart(time_key), 2, 'end');
```